# Sum multiple digit from datagridview and then sum cell values from specific column

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum

I have a datagridview column with values formed by multiple digits.

I'm tryng to obtain the sum of all cell value from this column but first I need to sum the digits in the single cell.

[column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cucJA.png)

Example: every cell has "201" value. I need to obtain "3" as result and then do the sum of all the rows values. So if I have 3 row with 201, I need to obtain 3 for each and then 9 as the total.

How can do this?

This is my code but it seems to give wrong results.

```
int sum4 = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++p)
        {
            sum4 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[p].Cells[4].Value);
        }

        int sum5 = 0;
        while (sum4 != 0)
        {
            sum5 += sum4 % 10;
            sum4 /= 10;
        }

        label22.Text = sum5.ToString();
```

Now with 3 rows it's giving me 9 as result, with 4 row give me 12 but when I have 5 row it's giving me 6!

EDIT

The solution provided works but I missed a step.

[image]

In my datagridview I need first to multiply the "Ripetizioni" value for the "Serie" value and then multiply this for the sum of seconds of the "Time under Tension" column. A the end the sum of all rows values.

So, for a single row I need the multiply of 11 x 3 (first wor example) then the sum of 201 with 3 as result and the multiply of 11x3= 33 x (sum of 201 result). At the end the sum of all rows

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need to add a separate question for this. One question per post is allowed.

Comment: ok, I'll create a new one, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. In your solution you are changing value of sum4 every time. This is wrong.

```
int finalSum = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++p)
  {
     finalSum += getCellDigitSum(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[p].Cells[4].Value));
  }
    
 label22.Text = finalSum.ToString();
    
 int getCellDigitSum(int cellValue)
   {
     int l = cellValue;
     int result = 0;
    
     while (l > 0)
       {
         result += (l % 10);
    
         l = l / 10;
       }
    
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: if this is working then upvote so that this can help others also.

Comment: I did it now. In the same datagridview I have a column with datetime value (mm:ss). How can I edit this code to sum all values and return the sum in seconds?

Comment: you need to pass the seconds value to function. First extract seconds from cell and then pass it to the function.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: you need to share your example cell and value. I will check on that. It will be more useful.

Comment: First I see that I missed a piece on the first question, see my edit please. Thank you very much